# Delphi component property class depending on the component's Owner class

Tags: delphi, vcl, design-time

I'm using RAD Studio XE5 to build my application.

I saw that is was not very practical to try tu publish properties on a TForm. It then has to be registered and installed as a package, then it's not practical for heavy development.

So, I decided I would create a non visual component (**TFormPropertiesEditor**) that would be used to fill up form properties. A way of standardising my forms.

The component would be dropped on the base form, a form of which every other form inherits (let's call it TBaseForm). So, **the component would be dropped only once on the 'base' form**, then with inheritance, every other form would have it too.

The created component would detect the class of its Owner (BaseForm or its descendents) and create an object accessible through the 'Properties' property, whose class would be conditional to the owner class.

This way, when inspecting the component on a TBaseForm, I would have access to the TBaseFormProperties only. When inspecting the component on a TSecondForm, I would also have access to the TSecondFormProperties. Only, the component would be intelligent enough to detect which PropertyClass it should expose as the **Properties** property.

The component would inspect the form, through the **GetPropertiesClass**,  defined as :

```
function TBaseForm.GetPropertiesClass : TPropertiesClass;
begin
  Result := TBaseFormProperties;
end;

function TSecondForm.GetPropertiesClass : TPropertiesClass;
begin
  Result := TSecondFormProperties;
end;
```

Each form has a corresponding TProperties descendent, like so :

```
TBaseForm ------------ TSecondForm ------------- ...
    |
TBaseFormProperties -- TSecondFormProperties --- ...
```

For example :

If the Form on which the component is placed is TBaseForm, FProperties would be a TBaseFormProperties. If the form is a TSecondForm, FProperties would be TSecondFormProperties. Naturally, TSecondFormProperties would inherit from TBaseFormProperties.

Though, when I place the component on the form, it seems to be unable to detect of which class the component is.

```
function TFormPropertiesEditor.GetPropertiesClass: TFormPropertiesClass;
begin
  Result :=  TBaseForm(Owner).GetPropertiesClass;  
end;
```

It looks like the TBaseForm(Owner) part is causing the problem. The interpreter is stuck on the TBaseForm, and will not consider if Owner is of type TSecondForm or TThirdForm.

**Interfaces**

So, to get around the TBaseForm(Owner) typecasting, I decided to use an interface. So if I use an interface that declares the GetPropertiesClass:

```
IMasterForm = interface(IInterface)
  ['{B6122F34-65C4-4701-8A5E-50C8DABF5516}']
  function GetPropertiesClass : TFormPropertiesClass;
  end;


type
  TBaseForm = class(TForm, IMasterForm)
    MyFormPropertiesEditor1: TMyFormPropertiesEditor;
  private
    { Déclarations privées }
  public
    function GetPropertiesClass : UCommon.TFormPropertiesClass;
  end;
```

The following :

```
function TFormPropertiesEditor.GetPropertiesClass : TFormPropertiesClass;
begin
  Result := (Owner as IMasterForm).GetPropertiesClass;
end;
```

Results into an **Interface not supported** error.

**Abstract Ancestor Method**

Then, I decided to add an extra layer of ancestry. I've added a class, TMasterForm, from which TBaseForm inherits. This TMasterForm declares GetPropertiesClass as abstract and virtual :

```
TMasterForm = class(TForm, IMasterForm)
    public
      function GetPropertiesClass : TFormPropertiesClass; virtual; abstract;
  end;


type
  TBaseForm = class(TMasterForm)
  private
    { Déclarations privées }
  public
    function GetPropertiesClass : UCommon.TFormPropertiesClass; override;
  end;
```

But then, I get an AV because I think the IDE tries to access TMasterClass.GetPropertiesClass, which is of course not implemented.

How can this TypeCasting be accomplished? Any idea how could I proceed ?

Thank you very much in advance

**Download Sample Project** https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/b524438609fc04257af803a8e3dd2eca20141225161239/764d108d335b9d296c3004dfea04a54620141225161240/9c8cc0

Comment: You didn't register your base form with the IDE. So at design time the form that you see is not of type `TBaseForm`. What you are attempting isn't going to work. I think that all your work is in vain. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Perhaps you need [`RegisterCustomModule`](http://www.marcocantu.com/ddh/ddh15/ddh15e.htm)...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think he is going about this the wrong way. Doesen't custom propertie editors of certain components use similar approach like this.

Comment: @Silver I don't see how the IDE is going to instantiate TBaseForm or indeed any derived classes. How will it know to do that?

Comment: Regarding your edit, did you read my comments? How is the IDE going to execute your code?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean now. Registering the component with the IDE would fix that?

Comment: Once you've registered the forms all the rest of your code is needless

Comment: But I won't be able to visually edit the published properties of the registered forms, but only the published properties of their descendants right?

Comment: Like @David already answered and explained, the Form object shown in the IDE is not of the designed Form class type, despite of that Form.ClassName dóes result in the expected string. But since you manually add a `TSpecificFormProperties` reference to each Form class anyway, I suggest to create an extra unit with a _loopup-table_ wherein to keep the `TSpecificForm`-`TSpecificFormProperties` combinations. Do this by `ClassName` so you have no mixup between project and package code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem here is that the IDE does not instantiate your form at designtime. So, no matter what code you put in the form class, it won't be executed by the IDE. This is because you did not register the form with the IDE.

If you wish the IDE to have knowledge of your forms then you need to register them with the IDE. And at that point all your code becomes needless because you are back to doing what you are attempting to avoid. Namely registering the forms with the IDE. You are stuck in a Catch 22 situation. If you need the IDE to know about the forms then you need to register them. At which point you may as well just surface the properties directly in the Object Inspector.

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your code is that you are not inheriting your GetPropertiesClass method properly.

Infact you are not inheriting it across the class family.

In your code each class type has its own version of GetPropertiesClass method and therefore since you are typecasting the Owner to a TBaseForm class the method from TBaseForm is being used even if Owner is of TSecondForm class.

So you need to make sure that GetPropertiesClass in TBaseForm class is virtual and that merhod GetPropertiesClass in TSecondForm is overrided.

This will ensure that TSecondForm.GetProperties method will be called even when you are typecasting Owner to TBaseClass when the owner is of TSeconfForm class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did that indeed. I even added another class, TMasterForm = class(TForm) which has the GetPropertiesClass abstract and virtual, from which the TBaseForm inherits. TBaseForm's GetPropertiesClass is declared overriden. Still, when I drop the component on the form, the IDE now tries to access TMasterForm's GetPropertiesClass, which result in AV as this method is abstract.